# general purpose util library or multiple specific dlls?

Tags: utilities, dll

Is it a better idea to dump 'utility' classes that are shared by multiple projects into a single utilities library, or to create many small assemblies each of which has to be loaded by the projects that use them?

I don't really like the idea of utility libraries, and you get a total mish-mash of functionality, but on the other hand having 20 dlls which each contain a single piece of functionality doesn't seem like a great solution either.

Is there a third way?

EDIT:
This is using .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to put utilities into one (or a few) bigger assemblies, but work with namespaces to get a clear structure among them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you will want to have your work distributed to your developers. It also depends if you want to reuse some of the classes later. And – if you have an utility class that is used in one single point in whole application – this is no longer utility class…

Answer (score 0):

I would go with one assembly, with namespaces.

Be vigilant about what goes into the utilities library when including in a lot of projects. 
Else you will be confronted with [something like this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/29/let-us-burn-all-those-pesky-util-amp-common-libraries.aspx).

Comment: Hahaha.  I think it was that post that prompted me to ask the question.